# How can I arrange k elements by frequency in Decreasing Order in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given the array (`array`) `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]` this method should return (`new_array`)
`[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3]`

Heres what I have tried so far

1. Converted array into hash
2. Key being the element and value being the count

How do I recreate the `array` again to match `new_array`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
array = [1,1,2,2,2,3]

array.tally # This is the bit you did already. Note that this uses the new ruby 2.7 method. You get: {1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>1}
  .sort_by {|k, v| -v} # Now we have: [[2, 3], [1, 2], [3, 1]]
  .flat_map { |element, count| Array.new(count, element) }

# And that gives the final desired result of:
[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3]
```

Or another variant, along the same lines:

```
array.tally # {1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>1}
  .invert # {2=>1, 3=>2, 1=>3}
  .sort # [[1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
  .reverse # [[3, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3]]
  .flat_map { |element, count| [element] * count }
```

Or, here's something completely different:

```
array.sort_by { |x| -array.count(x) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one:

```
array = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
p array.group_by(&:itself).values.sort_by(&:size).flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def sort_chunks_by_length(arr)
  arr.slice_when(&:!=).sort_by { |a| -a.size }.flatten
end
```

```
sort_chunks_by_length [1,1,2,2,2,3]
  #=> [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3] 
sort_chunks_by_length [1,1,2,2,2,1,3,3]
  #=> [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1]
```

I have assumed that for the second example the desired return value is as shown, as opposed to:

```
  #=> [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

The steps for that example are as follows.

```
arr = [1,1,2,2,2,1,3,3]
```

```
enum = arr.slice_when(&:!=)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007ffd1a9740b8>:each>
```

This is shorthand for:

```
enum = arr.slice_when { |x,y| x!=y }
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1], [3, 3]]
```

Continuing,

```
a = enum.sort_by { |a| -a.size }
  #=> [[2, 2, 2], [1, 1], [3, 3], [1]] 
a.flatten
  #=> [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1]
```

The operative line could be replaced by either of the following.

```
  arr.chunk(&:itself).map(&:last).sort_by { |a| -a.size }.flatten
  arr.chunk_while(&:==).sort_by { |a| -a.size }.flatten
```

See [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), [Enumerable#chunk](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) and [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while).

Comment: Your method assumes that the original array is pre-chunked. If it's not, e.g. `array=[1,2,1,2,2,3]`, then your logic with `slice_when` or `chunk_while` won't work.

Comment: I guess you could account for that by throwing an additional `sort` into the logic!

Comment: @Tom, as per my stated assumption, the desired return value for your example should be `[2,2,1,2,1,3]`, not `[2,2,2,1,1,3]`. Others have assumed the opposite. Either assumption may be correct as the question is mute on that point. It reflects the inadequacy of stating a question in terms of a single example, which we see all the time on SO.